# How to add a ejs value into a script's src url using node/ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to run a script from an API that I am trying to implement. I am supposed to run:

```
<script src="https://example.com?Id={Id}"></script>
```

where I am supposed to replace {Id}.

I am sending this `id` into the webpage in my route doing `res.render('/example', {id:id});`
I check and I have the correct `id` in the page, which I can get via ejs with `<%=id%>`.
But I am having trouble putting it into the script's src to get the script running.
I feel this is something silly I just dont know how to do.

Comment: Try using template strings by using backticks around url - <script src=`https://example.com?Id=${Id}`></script>
 or <script src="https://example.com?Id="+Id></script>

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to embed ejs is `<%=id%>` like you mentioned. 
So this should work:

```
<script src="https://example.com?Id=<%=id%>"></script>
```